# Proper way to initialize unique_ptr as class members wrapping C 'structs'

Tags: c++, class, c++17, unique-ptr

I'm trying to implement some openssl functionality in a C++ program. The openssl library requires a lot of memory allocation / deallocation. My approach is to pack the required structs from openssl into a class and allocate the memory with the constructor and deallocate it via the destructor.

Now I wanted to move to a different approach where each member is represented as a unique pointer with a deleter. This would mean that I would not have to rely on the destructor of the object to release the memory.

Let's say my class looks like this:

```
class OpensslSignature {
  public:
   OpensslSignature() = default;

   std::unique_ptr<X509, decltype(X509_free) *> cert{nullptr, X509_free};
   std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY, decltype(EVP_PKEY_free) *> pkey{nullptr, EVP_PKEY_free};

   void readCert(const std::string &name);
   void readKey(const std::string &key);
}
```

The implementation is like this:

```
void OpensslSignature::readCert(const std::string &name) {
  BIO *tmp = BIO_new_file(name.c_str(), "r");

  cert = std::unique_ptr<X509, decltype(X509_free) *>(PEM_read_bio_X509(tmp, NULL, 0, NULL), X509_free);

  BIO_free(tmp);

  if (!cert) {
    // error handling
  }
}

void OpensslSignature::readKey(const std::string &key) {
  // similiar to readCert
}
```

Is it correct to initialize unique_ptrs like this? Am I supposed to set them to nullptr in the header? Or would it be better to initialize them in a constructor?

Also when initializing the pointer in the readCert() function, do I really need to write the entire pointer definition again `std::unique_ptr<type, deleter>()`?

Or is it better to initialize with std::make_unique()?

Comment: Nitpick: you don't initialize in `readCert`; initialization happens before the constructor's body is executed. What you have is an assignment.

Comment: You don't need the initializer in the class definition. The default constructor will initialize both the underlying raw pointer and the deleter to `nullptr`.

Comment: You can't create a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter using `std::make_unique` – all its arguments are for the object constructor, not for the `unique_ptr`. It is also impossible to add such an overload for the general case, but of course nothing prohibits you from writing your own functions, or types.

Answer (score 1):

The general C++ principle here is RAII - Resource Acquisition Is Initialization. It's quite easy to search for that term online.

It also means that Initialization Is Resource Acquisition. Objects generally shouldn't be initialized to some unusable, empty state, where you then need to call another function to do the real work.

In this case, it looks like `OpensslSignature` has two parts, both of which should be classes in their own right. `X509_free` should be called from the destructor of some kind of Cert-type, while `EVP_PKEY_free` should be called from the destructor of some kind of "KeyPair" type.

The `OpensslSignature` constructor can then take those two types, and you won't need a `readCert` function anymore.

You can use a `unique_ptr` in both of the implementations, if you like. I'm not sure if that's exactly the easiest route, but that's a small matter. You'd make it `private` anyway, and if you later change the implementation that won't matter to code outside that class.